# SQL Query, count number of similar timestamp values and display sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query and would like to see the sum of the rows that share the same values.

```
select ca.createddate
from sss s
join ttt t on t.sssId = s.id
join ccc c on c.tttId = t.id
join ccc_assoc ca on ca.refid = c.id
where s.name = 'xyz'
```

Example query results:

```
Created_Date
11/29/2018 1:27:58 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:58 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:58 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:58 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:59 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:59 AM
11/29/2018 1:27:59 AM
```

What I would like to see:

```
Created_Date          | Count
11/29/2018 1:27:58 AM | 4
11/29/2018 1:27:59 AM | 3
```

I have tried playing with COUNT and GROUP BY but I'm not even sure I am in the right ball park with those functions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Got it. Thanks. We are using sql-server.

Comment: maybe `group by`?

Comment: What is the data type of `ccc_assoc.createddate`?

Comment: "I have tried playing with COUNT and GROUP BY".  So where's it?  I don't see it.

Comment: @a8e if some answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like?

```
SELECT ca.createddate AS Created_Date
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM sss s
JOIN ttt t ON t.sssId = s.id
JOIN ccc c ON c.tttId = t.id
JOIN ccc_assoc ca On ca.refid = c.id
WHERE s.name = 'xyz'
GROUP BY ca.createddate
```

Comment: Yep. It returns each row with a count of 1.

Comment: That means records from `ccc_assoc` are being duplicated. It may be the `JOIN` to `ccc`, or it might be higher in the join sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A novel approach would be to use a CTE to generate the list of dates, then aggregate the CTE. You might try it like this:

```
;WITH Dates AS
(
    select ca.createddate
    from sss s
    join ttt t on t.sssId = s.id
    join ccc c on c.tttId = t.id
    join ccc_assoc ca on ca.refid = c.id
    where s.name = 'xyz'
)
SELECT 
    createddate, 
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfDates
GROUP BY createddate
```

EDIT: This is not really the best way to do this, though. It's more of a "quick and dirty" method. Ideally you would track down where your rows are getting duplicated and then group by the singleton's key

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the date that you see is not really what is there -- there are likely to be milliseconds.

If you want single second precision, you can remove smaller time units using date arithmetic or by converting to a string.  Try this:

```
select dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, ca.createddate), 0) as ts,
       count(*)
from sss s join
     ttt t on t.sssId = s.id join
     ccc c on c.tttId = t.id join
     ccc_assoc ca on ca.refid = c.id
where s.name = 'xyz'
group by dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, ca.createddate), 0)
order by ts;
```